# Do not understand this paper's variant of the spectral theorem and spectral decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading the article "The Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse. A Tutorial Review of the Theory" found in the PDF-file linked directly [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.746.4482&rep=rep1&type=pdf). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUzE1.png) is a (shamefully uncropped) screenshot of the theorem.

But I'm having great difficulties to understand a specific detail in its version of *the Spectral Theorem for Matrices* which it presents in **Theorem A.9** on page 15 (in the PDF-file).

The detail that I fail to understand is what the article means by the matrix $\delta$ (I'm assuming it's a matrix, the matrix is mentioned at the absolute end of page 15 among many other places). The article uses this matrix and the notation "$\delta$" freely without at all explaining what it signifies.

So could someone please help me to understand what the article means by "$\delta$"? Could someone also refer me to some material that presents *the Spectral Theorem for Matrices* in the version it's presented in this article and explain it more thoroughly?

I apologize for not copy-pasting the theorem in my question here, but I'm completely new to Stackexchange and have no idea how to produce all the multitudes of various symbols and notations.

Regards!

Comment: This probably isn't as big an issue for a scholarly paper, but external links are generally frowned upon. Might be best to type in what you are having trouble with, or at least a screen grab.

Comment: @The Count, I've now inserted a screenshot (linked, since I'm not allowed to embed). If it's ok I'll keep the pdf-link for reference since I didn't manage to get all the interesting parts into one screenshot :-/

Comment: That's fine. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the Kronecker-Delta. That is $\delta_{i,j}=\begin{cases}
0 & \mbox{ if } i\neq j,\\
1 & \mbox{ if } i=j.
\end{cases}$

Comment: Oh M G yes, thank you! This makes sense when I look through the text again. It also makes sense that they didn't bother explaining the notation since it seems to be so trivial (although I wish they had explained it).